# How to identify the system time is set to 12hrs or 24hrs in javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, datetime, systemtime

When I do "new date()" in javascript it gives the time in 24hrs.
I want to know whether the user has set the system time to 12hrs or 24hours in javascript.

Is there any way to detect this in javascript?